# How to take results five by five from an ActiveRecord in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose:

```
  @articles =(Article.find.all).some_method
```

I want to loop for @articles variable in such way the results will be as this:

```
[ [article1Obj, article2Obj, article3Obj, article4Obj, article5Obj], [article6Obj, article7Obj, article8Obj, article9Obj, article10Obj], [...], [...],......,[...] ].
```

a list of lists, each contains five elements or generally *n* elements.

Is there any method in Rails can do that with a simple way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@articles = Article.all.in_groups_of(5)
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of

This will load all of the articles up from the database, and give you an array of arrays, where each inner array has 5 articles in it.

Now, if you have a lot of articles in your database, this will quickly be a lot of results, so you’ll want to paginate your results accordingly.

Comment: Thanks very much. That's exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @errazoid Great! If it solves your problem, would you be able to “Accept” my answer?

Comment: I guess It's done. Sorry i am new here I can't yet  vote  for your amazing answer. :(

Comment: It’s all good! The green check mark is all I was hoping for. Thanks!

Comment: APIDock isn't really maintained anymore, you're better off linking to the official docs: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of . Or, if you don't need the `fill_with` behavior of `in_groups_of`, go straight to [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice).

Comment: I didn’t realize that. Thanks @muistooshort

Comment: Yeah, shame, the version tracking was sometimes handy.